# PL/SQL Can I cast a %TYPE variable from a function to DATE?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g

My case is the following: I want to make a query to the database and one of the fields I would like to get is a result from a called function. The problem is that the function's return type is declared as `%TYPE` which is associated with some column's data type in some table. However in that query I need to get this field as a `DATE`. Is there a possible way to cast this function's result to a `DATE` data type?

query:

```
select t1.some_field    as A,
       t1.another_field as B,
       my_function()    as C
  from my_table t1;
```

function's spec:

```
create or replace function my_function as
(
param1 default null
)
return my_table2.column_name%TYPE;
```

Comment: What is the data type of `my_table2.column_name%TYPE`?  Is that a `DATE`?  A `TIMESTAMP`?  If not, how would you convert it to a `DATE` (is it a `VARCHAR2` in a specific format, for example)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. The type of the field in that table is just a DATE

Comment: There really isn't a question here. Just doing it would reveal that it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since `my_table.column_name%TYPE` just resolves to a `DATE`, there is no need to cast it-- the data type of `C` in your query will automatically be a `DATE`.

If, in the future, someone changes the data type of the column in the table, the data type returned by the function would change (assuming the function declaration did not change).  That would change the data type of column `C`.  But in that case, you're realistically going to need to change the query anyway if you want to return a `DATE` since you'll have to add logic to cast the data from whatever data type the column changed to into a `DATE`.